# Removing certain regular expressions in r

Tags: r, regex, line-breaks

I have a character string in which I would like to only remove the line breaks followed immediately by a lowercase letter. For example, my string might contain:

> one line of text \r\n another line \r\nof text,

which would show up as:

> one line of text
>
> another line
>
> of text.

In this example, I would only want to remove the second line break, so that the text would then read:

> one line of text
>
> another line of text

I know that the pattern is "\r\n[a-z]", and so the code should be something like

```
gsub("\r\n[a-z]","")
```

but I cannot come up with code that removes the line break while retaining the lowercase letter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround

```
txtN <- gsub("\r\n(?=[a-z])", "", txt, perl = TRUE)
cat(txtN, sep="\n")
# one line of text 
# another line of text,
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You may achieve what you need without lookarounds and use a TRE regex like

```
s <- "one line of text \r\n another line \r\nof text,"
res <- gsub("\r?\n([a-z])","\\1", s)
cat(res)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/uehdtC)

If you use the `(...)` around a pattern you define a *capturing group* the contents of which you may reference from the replacement pattern.

*Pattern details*:

- `\r?\n` - a linebreak (either `\r\n` or `\n`)
- `([a-z])` - a lowercase ASCII letter inside Group 1.

*Replacement*:

- `\1` - a numbered backreference to the Group 1 contents.

*More information about*:

- [Capturing groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)
- [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html)

P.S.: If you are keen to use PCRE regex, there is one very nice construct other than a lookahead support - a `\R` that matches any style linebreak. Then, I'd suggest:

```
gsub("\\R(?=[a-z])", "", txt, perl = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `positive lookahead` for this.

For instance:

```
text = "one line of text \r\n another line \r\nof text,"

fixed = gsub("\r\n(?=[a-z])", "", text, perl = T)

cat(fixed)
#> one line of text 
#>  another line of text,
```

Comment: This is similar to the one I posted